# any ssh command returns error: ssh_depotgis_xmpp_abilan : command not found

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.3, and I am trying to connect to an ssh bastion.
But any command starting with `ssh` (such as `ssh -V`) returns an error for which I cannot find any documentation:

```
ssh_depotgis_xmpp_abilan : command not found
```

I have tried updating/upgrading openssh-client ('sudo apt upgrade openssh-client', already up-to-date) and all packages (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`), nothing changed.

Answers to comments/suggestions:

- Nothing related in .bashrc or .bash_aliases, or in the result from the command `alias`.
- `which ssh` and `ls -l "$(which ssh)"` both return `/usr/bin/ssh`
- The command `/usr/bin/ssh -V` returns:

`OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`

but `ssh -V` returns the error message *ssh_depotgis_xmpp_abilan : command not found*

- using bash, `hash -r`does not return anything

Comment: A naive suggestion : could it be a command alias?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I did not find anything related to this name in .bashrc or .bash_aliases, or in the results from the command `alias`...

Comment: Does your `ssh` command resolve to `/usr/bin/ssh` (try : `which ssh` and `ls -l "$(which ssh)"`)? Same error message if you run `/usr/bin/ssh -V`?

Comment: Yes, both commands return `/usr/bin/ssh`. The command `/usr/bin/ssh -V` returns :  `OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, `ssh -V` returns "_ssh_depotgis_xmpp_abilan : command not found_" but `/usr/bin/ssh -V` returns the correct (expected) message?

Comment: What's your shell, bash, zsh, something else? What''s the output of `type ssh`? Try `hash -r` if using bash.

Comment: Hello, It turns out it was a problem with the BASH config made by the admin. @Grobu: thank you for your help anyway!